# Break HTML page if certain code is missing

Tags: html, xhtml

trying to create a page that if someone copies my page and removes my copyright information (which I might encrypt) the page will fail to load correctly, therefore the code will be needed for the site to work. I am also considering hosting the css file remotely, so that I can change parts of the site if needed. I am trying to create a site that If another person copies my site and tries to remove my trademarks it will not load the site. Thanks.

Comment: the key thing for you to realize here is the differentiation between the client side (html, js, applets, etc..) and the server side (php, jsp). people loading your page only "see" the client side, and so this is all they could possibly copy (unless they had access to your server). the bottom line is that you can't protect your client side code. you can obfuscate it but if it displays in a user's browser he will be able to recreate it elsewhere. encrypting your copyright information is really quite useless because of the points made above.

Comment: I understand that side, the idea came from a js that I used a while back, when I removed the copyright information at the top, the js stopped working. I thought that I can make it so the css wont load or work correctly if a piece of code was missing from my html code. Since the person I am targeting is not familiar with the html side of things I was hoping that he would miss my copyright information and copy my site with my copyright data intact. (for legal reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Anything you might do will either:

1. Be trivially easy to defeat by removing a piece of JS *or*
2. Be trivially easy to defeat by copy/pasting from a DOM viewer

HTML and web browsers are not designed in a way that allows DRM.